# How can I force quit bash?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running the Windows Subsystem for Linux, and for some reason the bash window is not closing. I started Task Manager in order to force quit it, but it's not showing up as a process.

How can I force quit out of bash?

(For now, I will just restart my computer, but it would be nice to know how to quit without having to do this.)

Image:
[image: Bash Image]

EDIT:
So, I found the process under "Windows Processes >> System >> Select ..."
[image]

When I click on "Bring to front", it does indeed bring up the window that won't close.

However, as you can see in the image, when I try to "End task" it merely says "not responding" for a few seconds and stays up.

Comment: Which bash process? Is it `bash.exe` from Windows or `/bin/bash` from Linux? Provide a screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried typing the command `exit`?

Comment: @DrZoo I have two screens that are just frozen and not running. I can open and close other screens, but those two remain open regardless of what I do. The "close" button reacts on them, but they don't actually close. The "close all windows" button doesn't close them. So I need a way to force quit.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Image added. I don't know the difference between the two.

Comment: I think that process is `bash.exe` in task manager. You can open task manager and check if any `bash.exe` commands are there. If they are, you can right click on it and select `End Process`. That should close them.

Comment: I couldn't find anything called `bash.exe`. I force quit Ubuntu, but that still leaves the windows up. (Actually, I guess there's only one window. I think I mis-counted before or one was able to shut down.)

Comment: For the record, restarting my computer did work.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me to quit out of these windows was to click on them and then hit any button. I don't know why this works. (Maybe it gives focus to the window so it actually responds to events? Idk.) But after I did this, the window responded to all previous actions and if I had clicked the "X" before, it closed. (And if I hadn't, clicking the "X" then worked.